# search a jquery autocomplete plugin

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

User enters tag in the textbox. The textbox is a live search as the user types it brings up suggester results based on the tags already in the system, simiral to stackoverflow tag input :) Tags are separated by commas, so when a user selects a result from the livwe search, it automatically populates the text and a trailing comma

does anybody know such plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autocomplete is now part of [jQuery UI 1.8](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete).

Answer (score 0):

jquery 1.4.x and jqueryui 1.8.x now support a built in autocomplete

The results must be formatted as a json array coming back from your script

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete

There is also another popular one here:
http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

Answer (score 0):

This is the original JQuery autocomplete plugin before it was moved to JQueryUI.
If you are looking to serve just JQuery but not JQueryUI, use this one.

[http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)/

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness' sake, maybe you will like the original standalone jQuery autocompleter plugin that is still around (and actively developed):

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/